# Creating polygon with attributes using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, fields-attributes, polygon-creation

I'm new of the use of arcGIS.
I have xy data that descibe a polygon. But when I use the tool "point to line" I lost all attributes. There is a way to create a polygon with attributes. I try to explain with an example

Example
x (25 125 55 36),
y (25 336 12 12),
turtle: 3

x and y are the cordinates that describe a sea portion sea. Inside this part there were three sightings of turtles. How can I create a polygon that with the number of sightings in other to create a map of density?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.

Comment: Can you please provide exact format of the input point data? What represent numbers in parenthesis? How is your data stored?

Comment: I agree with @AlexTereshenkov - that is not an XY format that I recognize - I think you need to edit your question (there is an edit button beneath it) to explain it before we will be able to try and answer your question.

Comment: Please indicate if you intend to do this in python or ArcObjects... it is probably not be possible in model builder or any existing tool.